# amcharts index.js is rejected by loadScript() in LWC with empty exception

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, error, javascript-debugging

We tried to include amcharts5 libraries - index.js, animated.js and xy.js in LWC. Animated.js and xy.js is loaded properly in LWC but index.js is failing with an empty exception and it goes inside the catch.

when we checked in chrome console under sources - > resources, index.js is loaded but console shows warning and empty exception. From console we understand that LWC doesn't support something in index.js which is not secure.

Is there any way we can use amcharts with LWC. Aura component also fails to load index.js.
Any suggestions/inputs will be hightly appreciated.

Lightning Web Component - API Version 50 (Tried with higher versions)
amcharts Library Version - (Tried with 4 as well)

[image: loadScript LWC snippet]

[image: Failed to load script warning with undefined error in chrome console]